# How to solve: Grafana has failed to load its application files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, grafana

I want to run Grafana in a specific domain, but this problem is encountered

Grafana image version is 9.1.0

docker-compose:

```
version: "3.8"

services:

  grafana:
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_GRAFANA}
    image: grafana/grafana:9.1.0
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      TZ: Asia/Tehran
      GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER: ${GRAFANA_ADMIN_USER}
      GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${GRAFANA_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - grafana-data:/var/lib/grafana
      - ./docker/grafana/grafana.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini
      #- /etc/grafana/provisioning
    ports:
      - "${GRAFANA_PORT}:3000"
```

grafana.ini:

```
[server]
# Protocol (http, https, h2, socket)
;protocol = http

# The ip address to bind to, empty will bind to all interface

;http_addr =

# The http port  to use
;http_port = 3000

# The public facing domain name used to access grafana from a browser
domain = ${GRAFANA_DOMAIN}

# Redirect to correct domain if host header does not match domain
# Prevents DNS rebinding attacks
;enforce_domain = false

# The full public facing url you use in browser, used for redirects and emails
# If you use reverse proxy and sub path specify full url (with sub path)
root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s/
```

---

[image: Grafna error]

If you're seeing this Grafana has failed to load its application files

1. This could be caused by your reverse proxy settings.
2. If you host grafana under subpath make sure your grafana.ini root_url setting includes subpath. If not using a reverse proxy make sure to set serve_from_sub_path to true.
3. If you have a local dev build make sure you build frontend using: yarn start, yarn start:hot, or yarn build
4. Sometimes restarting grafana-server can help
5. Check if you are using a non-supported browser. For more information, refer to the list of supported browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect, that you are missing a `GRAFANA_DOMAIN: ${GRAFANA_DOMAIN}` in your `docker-compose.yml`. You need to pass through this environment variable so it is available inside the container.

Comment: thanks for your answer, My problem is not from the environment variable, because I manually changed the domain value inside the container, but the problem was not solved, Grafana comes up with IP and port, but not with domain

Comment: Okay, can you try to debug the issue? Open the developer tools in your browser, reload the page and look at the network tab. Are there any failed requests that you see?